# c# there is already an open datareader associated with this command which must be closed first

Tags: c#

I want to search data from another SQL Server table (`Stocks_Item`) to this form (IC) `dataGridView1`, I can view that data (from `Stocks_Item`) in this `dataGridView1` but I couldn't search. Please help me.

Here is my code:

```
 private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
       conn.Close();

       try
       {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand("Select * from Stocks_Item where Stock_No = @Stocks_no", conn);
                selectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Stocks_no", txtsearch_stock_no.Text.ToString()));
                SqlDataReader reader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();
                bool rowFound = reader.HasRows;


                SqlDataAdapter data = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Stocks_Item", conn);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                data.Fill(dt);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

                /* SqlDataAdapter sda;
                 DataTable dt1;
                 sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select * FROM colombo_branch ",conn);
                 dt1 = new DataTable();
                 sda.Fill(dt1);
                 dataGridView.DataSource = dt1;*/
                MessageBox.Show("Search Found", "Form", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

    conn.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There are many flaws in your code, but the one that is specifically causing your error is because you are not properly closing the `SqlDataReader` here:

```
SqlDataReader reader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();
bool rowFound = reader.HasRows;
```

As a result, the following line, which also attempts to open a data reader internally throws the exception:

```
data.Fill(dt);
```

Normally, you want to use a `SqlDataReader` inside a `using` block, something like:

```
bool rowFound;
using(SqlDataReader reader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader())
{
    rowFound = reader.HasRows;
}
```

... to ensure proper and timely disposal. But in this case, I fail to see the point of that block of code anyways. So why not just remove it altogether?

---

Additional comments:

- Avoid global connections. The fact that the method begins by closing the connection is not a good sign.
- Always use `using` blocks around your `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`, `SqlDataReader`, `SqlDataAdapter`, etc... instances to make sure you don't run into these types of errors or leak resources.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that SqlDataAdapter opens/closes a connection for you. Since you're doing that earlier in your code and using a reader against it, that would be the cause.  You could use either the reader or the adapter, but typically wouldn't want to mix them in one connection without properly closing/disposing.

FYI, the [MSDN SqlDataAdapter code example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_8) utilizes this auto open/close behavior of SqlDataAdapter